# Are pro and prae etymologically related?

Tags: etymology, preposition

*Pro* and *prae* are somewhat similar in meaning and form. De Vaan isn't clear about whether they are related; he mentions Proto-Indo-European roots **proH* or **pro*, and **pre-h2i*, respectively. Could it be some kind of ablaut?

Answer (score 4):

In theory, *preh²i could be the locative singular of *proH, with e-grade ablaut (and possibly a different laryngeal?). I think this is what de Vaan is suggesting, if in a somewhat roundabout way.